# Can not install Ubuntu server because "Install" option is not available

Tags: installation, server

I am following along [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-setup-a-dedicated-web-server-for-free/) tutorial.

I got the bootable usb flash drive made, booted from it and selected my language. The problem is during the next *Ubuntu Install* screen. For some reason there is no option to "Install Ubuntu Server" or even *Check CD for defects*. Only the last three options are available. Why are those options not available? Is there a way for me to install Ubuntu Server?

I'm trying to install the server on an old Acer Laptop with 1GB of RAM, and 2.2GHz AMD processor. Also, the only operating system on the local disk is a version of *BackTrack Linux*, not sure if thats worth mentioning.

ALSO, when I go to the "memtest" option, it seems to fail and only reports "Cannot load a ramdisk with an old kernel image". No idea that means, possibly related?

---

But yes I was trying both "Universal USB Installer" from pendrivelinux.com as well as unetbootin and both were doing the same exact thing (no option to actually INSTALL the server, just other options). I finally found something called "YUMI" which is also available from pendrivelinux.com. They call it a "multiboot", but I used it just fine to get my single ubuntu server.

Although now I am getting errors that the GRUB won't install correctly, the endless battle continues :(

Comment: Please download the Ubuntu Server .iso (I suggest 12.04 LTS 32bit, just to be on the safe side) from the official site, then check its integrity by comparing the md5 sums in 'http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.3/'

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same issue. Which program did you use to create the bootable USB flash drive? I was using the "Universal USB Installer" from pendrivelinux.com and I could only see the last 2 options. If you use "unetbootin" you should be able to see all options available